# How to specify @RequestMapping params in MockMvc

Tags: java, spring-mvc, testing, mockito, mockmvc

I have a controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/bookForm")
public class BookFormController {

    @Autowired
    private BookHttpRequestParser parser;

    @Autowired
    private BooksService booksService;

    @RequestMapping(params = "add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addBook(HttpServletRequest request) {
        try {
            Book newBook = parser.createBookFromRequest(request);
            booksService.addBook(newBook);
        } catch (InvalidTypedParametersException e) {

        }
        return "redirect:index.html";
    }
```

This Controller has a method for adding book to DB. Method has @RequestMapping annotation with **params = "add"** value.

Im trying to set this params criteria to controller unit test method:

```
@Test
public void addBook() throws Exception{
    HttpServletRequest request = mock(HttpServletRequest.class);
    Book book = new Book();
    when(parser.createBookFromRequest(request)).thenReturn(book);

    mockMvc.perform(post("/bookForm", "add"))
    .andExpect(status().isOk())
    .andExpect(view().name("redirect:index.html"));
}
```

Where to specify this @ResuetsMapping params value?

This:

> mockMvc.perform(post("/bookForm", **"add"**))

doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work.

`mockMvc.perform(post("/bookForm?add="))`

Answer (score 0):

use `RequestBuilder requestBuilders;`

object to build your request

```
requestBuilders = MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("URL/{Pathvariable}","PathvariableValue")
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .header("HeaderName", HeaderValue)
                    .param("ParameterName", "Value")
                    .param("ParameterName", "Value")
                    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
```

and the perfrom

```
mockMvc.perform(requestBuilders)
                    .andDo(print())
                    .andExpect(status().isOk())
                    .andReturn();
```